# TestCafe on a Mac - no admin privileges

Tags: macos, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to set up testing with TestCafe on my work Mac. However, every time I try to run my tests, I get the message about TestCafe requiring Screen Recording privileges:

```
TestCafe requires permission to record the screen. Open 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Recording' and check 'TestCafe Browser Tools' in the application list.
```

I would normally enable this via System Preferences, but my machine is locked down, and I do not have admin privileges to do so. Is there **any** way to get TestCafe working on a Mac WITHOUT that privilege?  I've found various posts saying it depends on which version you run (I've tried v1.18.0 and latest without luck. I also tried adding the `--disable-screenshots` flag, but that does nothing.

When typing `npm run test`, I expected my tests to run. Instead, I received this message:

```
TestCafe requires permission to record the screen. Open 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Recording' and check 'TestCafe Browser Tools' in the application list.

Press any key to retry.
ERROR UnableToAccessScreenRecordingAPIError: The find-window process cannot access the Screen Recording API.
    at runFindWindowBinary (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/src/api/find-window.js:36:19)
    at Object.default_1 (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/src/api/find-window.js:43:15)
    at checkAuthentication (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe/src/cli/authentication-helper.ts:28:26)
    at Object.authenticationHelper [as default] (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe/src/cli/authentication-helper.ts:54:30)
    at Runner._checkRequiredPermissions (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/index.js:551:27)
    at Runner._validateBrowsers (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/index.js:305:13)
    at Runner._validateRunOptions (~/dev/e2e-testing/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/index.js:462:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe requires permissions to manipulate browser windows and capture screenshots and videos. And, these permissions can be enabled only by a user with administrator privileges. It is a limitation of MacOS.

As a workaround, you can run your tests with a [remote](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#remote-browsers) browser alias.